# Facebook Graph API Query Limit for places?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can anyone explain to me what is happening in the following scenario?

I enter the following URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=United-States&type=place&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&limit=1000

Facebook only returns 411 places and then when I execute the 'next' paging there are no places returned.

It seems like there is a limit or something stopping me from seeing more results. This is shown in both only showing 411 the first time and then the paging not working either. Has anyone encountered this and/or got a work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like to me, when I run this query, I only see places where I or a friend have liked that place.

In my experience, Facebook's location APIs are buggy at best.

If you're trying to find all the places, you're better off using a third-party service (I've been looking at [Factual](http://developer.factual.com/)) to find this information, then query the Facebook API for the data you need about that info.

Comment: Hi cpliko, 

The place I see aren't limited to my friends, but I do agree that the API is buggy. I submitted a bug report to Facebook and they have said they'll look into it which says to me that my expected behavior is correct. However, if anyone has any other ideas I'd love to hear them.

Comment: See Factual. They are the provider of location data to Facebook. Link in my original answer.

Comment: Factual looks good however I don't think it suits my purposes I'm querying Facebook to find a list of places with Facebook ids, I then use the Id from there.